# Import css without overlapping other css containers

Tags: html, css

**Solution:**
I asked this question way back with little knowledge in HTML and Javascript. I am sorry for that, anyway the solution here is to not use the same container name to prevent it overlapping other css containers.

**Question asked way back ago with little knowledge in JS**

How can I import an bootstrap.css file without overwriting other css files?? Is there any way to prevent this? I wish to safe time.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="style/shoppingcartstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "overwriting other css files"? Your server provides the files style.css, bootstrap.css, and shoppingcartstyle.css... so no collision.

Comment: I think what he means is .container would not be over-written by bootstrap's .container ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap.css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
```

Your issue after this lies with any !important declared tags in the bootstrap CSS, however anything you write into style.css will not be over-written by bootstrap otherwise, to ensure - if there's something that's important as you declare it in your style.css, add the !important tag, that overrules any previous declarations made by the bootstrap.css - it's a tag there to be used, great when working with UI frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to link to the bootstrap style sheet before every other one.

Should be

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
   <link href="style/shoppingcartstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The rules for CSS rule cascading are complex -rather than trying to paraphrase them badly, I'll simply refer you to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade):

Using the !important tag is a sign of a not very well put together website, however you can use this to over ride all other style rules.

Example

```
p{
    color:#FFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I mean, for instance if I have .btn-primary both inside style.css and bootstrap.css, it will overwrite eachother.